# Python SSL Error - cert issues vs. SSL disabled

Tags: python, ssl, handshake

I'm using **Python 3.5.2** to create a script to simply check if SSLv3 is enabled on a given host/port. Unfortunately, it seems `ssl.SSLContext.wrap_socket()` *returns* the same error

> (SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE)

under the following two conditions:

1. SSLv3 is disabled on the host or
2. certificate hostname mismatch or other problems exist.

Is there a way to differentiate these? I don't care about the SNI type problems in the current application. Are there other conditions that will return the same error as well?

Comment: Does SSLv3 even support SNI?  [RFC 3546](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3546.txt) only mentions TLSv1.

Comment: @AndrewHenle SNI was designed for TLS.

Comment: @EugèneAdell *SNI was designed for TLS.*  That's what I thought, too.  But I haven't found anything definitive that explicitly states that SSLv3 doesn't support SNI - hence I haven't answered.  Would using `openssl s_client ...` with SNI and limiting it to SSLv3 be definitive if it generates an "SSLv3 does not support SNI" error message?

Comment: @AndrewHenle [SSLv3 Client Hello](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6101#appendix-A.4.1) doesn't support extensions and SNI is an extension. By the time SSLv3 was written, they of course didn't know that extensions would be used later. I am not sure of the behaviour of `s_client`, and we cannot consider it as _the_ reference. At the protocol level, things which are not understood may be ignored.

Comment: As I said, I don't care about the SNI aspect. :-) Just trying to differentiate between 'no SSLv3' and 'bad cert'